# Android ArrayList and growing Object[] instances in heap

Tags: android, arraylist, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have "following code" in my app:

```
...
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            ...
            firstArrayList.add(new CustomObject());
            ...
            secondArrayList.add(new Integer(integer1));
            secondArrayList.add(new Integer(integer2));
            ...
            if(roundOverCondition){
                firstArrayList.clear();
                secondArrayList.clear();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
...
```

I did four heap dumps in eclipse.

1. befor the Thread is started
2. after the Thread is running a while; roundOverCondition was never true, yet
3. directly after roundOverCondition was true the first time (size of firstArrayList is 230)
4. directly after roundOverCondition was true the second time (size of firstArrayList is 200)

Thats the result:

- heap dump 2 shows that instances of Integer, CustomObject and java.lang.Object[] exist in heap
- heap dump 3 shows that no more instances of Integer and CustomObject exist heap. All instances of java.lang.Object[] still exist
- heap dump 4 shows that even more instances of java.lang.Object[] exist in heap (no instances of Integer and CustomObject)

The developing/behaviour of the number of instances of Integer and CustomObject is as expected. But what are this java.lang.Object[] instances ? And why thy doesn't get garbage collected?

Thx & regards :)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayLists are backed by, well, arrays.  The `Object[]` instances you're seeing in the heap dump were likely created by `ArrayList` as a side-effect of adding items to the list.

Consult the [docs for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and experiment with the sized constructor (or ensureCapacity()) to test the hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutly right. Inside ArrayList elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity); is called if size gets bigger then the capacity. But there still a few things unclear to me:

Comment: Even if ArrayList has to "resize" its internal data-array(elementData) everytime I add a new Object there should exist just one instance of Object[] in the heap per each ArrayList, right? Does ArrayList leak!?

Comment: This is an implementation detail of ArrayList; you generally can't presume a class's internals have a specific behavior beyond what is specified by its public interfaces.  It's unlikely a class as heavily used as ArrayList has a leak.  Inspect both the outstanding referents (in your heap dump) as well as the source if you want to be certain.